# объясните пожалуйста смысл этой ошибки в консоле?

Tags: html

объясните пожалуйста смысл этой ошибки в консоле
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Файл не найден. Возможно ошибка из-за того, что `style/images/...` не содержит картинок.

Comment: дак пишу  background: url(img/b3.jpg)/*tpa=http://test-task.dostavka2.me/img/b3.jpg*/ no-repeat center top;

Comment: @vitalyslobodyanyuk Вы говорите, что пишите url (img/b3.jpg), указываете img, тогда как в тексте ошибки была указана папка image, перепроверьте правильность путей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте пути, названия папок и файлов, и расширения. К примеру style или styles, папка Image, image, images или Images. Расширения .jpg или .jpeg, и т.д.